# Where should I put my finite state machine in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, model-view-controller, state-machine

I have a single MKAnnotationView that changes it's image based on various situations in my app.

I'm building a finite state machine that defines each of these states and interprets events that bring them about.

I'm considering building my state machine inside a subclass of MKAnnotationView that I only assign to the user location annotation, and then sending it messages based on events.

Is this a good idea? Or should my state machine should be a singleton, kind of hovering and separated from the objects themselves?

Thanks

Comment: What are the events? What has that knowledge? The view controller that owns the map (and annotation)?

Comment: @Wain The knowledge/events are in the MapViewController and a LocationController object that has my location manager and also checks the accuracy of user location.

Comment: If the FSM is general in design, I'd make it a general class/group of classes, with no specific "affinity" for any other set of APIs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't go singleton unless the state of the machine should be consistent across multiple annotations on multiple views.

I would generally be looking at giving the ownership to the view controller which owns the annotation. The view controller subscribes to all of the events and updates the state machine, it then applies the state machine result to the annotation.

Comment: +1 Indeed.  Employing the delegate pattern with a state machine is like bread and butter.

Comment: @JodyHagins Great! Going to do that. Any advice/tips&tricks about using FSM & Delegate pattern?

Comment: Create a protocol that has delegate callback methods for state changes.  Add a delegate property to your FSM.  Then, in your FSM, invoke the delegate for each state change with the familiar 'Will/Did' pattern.